# GitHub WebHooks triggered globally instead of per branch

Tags: github, github-api, webhooks

Our product creates WebHooks at GitHub. One for each customer project.

Each such project, is linked to a single branch.

When a `push` to GitHub is performed, the corresponding WebHook is triggered, which in its turn, is making a request to an endpoint on our side to perform a certain action.

A common scenario is that a customer would have several projects, connected to several different branches of the same repository. Hence, several different WebHooks are connected to the same repository.

The problem is that when a `push` is performed to one of the branches, GitHub triggers all repository related WebHooks.

We would expect that when a push is made to a certain branch, only a single corresponding WebHook would be triggered.

I found two posts (one of them is from 2012) that seem to refer to this problem:

- [Web Hooks - execute only for specified branches](http://Web%20Hooks%20-%20execute%20only%20for%20specified%20branches)
- [Ability to select a specific branch in webhook](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/issues/4105)

A possible solution would be to parse the `ref` parameter sent inside the webhook request and control when to take action accordingly (haven't checked that direction yet, and hope `ref` indeed always exists and holds the right branch path/name). But that will be "too late" - cause all WebHooks will have been triggered by then...

But seems unreasonable that GitHub wouldn't have a way to configure this behavior somehow.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Parse a single webhooks for push events and filter by branch. Alternatively, you could fork each customer project where each repo has separate webhooks.

Comment: @osowskit how would that be implemented in a Jenkins job? Would you just need to specify the branch in the refspec field for the repo? If not I'm not aware of a build trigger plugin for parsing a payload and matching refs to determine whether or not to build (but maybe one exists?)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I've reached out GitHub support.

I hope this post would help others, who misunderstand the relation between WebHooks and repositories / branches.

Here's their answer:

> The behavior you observed is expected and there are no plans to change
>   it in the near future.
>
> When you create a webhook on a repository and subscribe it to the push
>   event -- the webhook will trigger when any branch or tag is pushed to,
>   as documented here:
>
> https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent
>
> There are no per-branch webhooks.
>
> So, instead of creating multiple webhooks subscribed on the push event
>   on the same repository, you should create only one, and check which
>   branch was pushed to from the payload you receive (as you noticed, the
>   name of the branch is passed via the ref field in the payload).

This answer made us realize our conception was wrong.

Branches are not mapped to webhooks. 
Each WebHook is linked to a repository, and when a commit to a branch is made, the branch is stated inside the `ref` attribute inside the WebHook web request, like this:

```
 {
  "ref": "refs/heads/branch_name",
  ...
```

Another thing to note is that GitHub limits the number of WebHooks to be created per Repository-Event:

> You can create up to 20 webhooks for each event on each installation
>   target (specific organization or specific repository).

It was taken from here:

https://developer.github.com/webhooks/

That's important in this context, cause the creation of a WebHook per branch for the `push` event, made us reach that limit of 20 WebHooks, thus causing errors when trying to create additional WebHooks.

Keeping it at one WebHook per repository would eliminate that problem.

Comment: any resolution to your problem? I'm facing the same issue. *Any* push to the repo triggers both *dev* and *stage* builds. Highly annoying.

Comment: Did you follow my answer regarding the "ref" attribute?

Comment: yes I did. But the problem seems to be with github, and when the hook is triggered.

Comment: Carefully check your code and how you read the "ref". I have a strong feeling that it's your implementation rather than a problem with GitHub...

Comment: push to certain branch triggers something is a common scenario. GitHub's design choice (not support it) produces a lot of unnecessary network requests, and, **more importantly**, forces any webhook receiver who requires this feature to implement the parsing ref logic (it could have been implemented just once at GitHub).

Comment: For implementing in Jenkins, would you just need to specify the branch in the refspec field in the job and the job will automatically verify it with the ref in the payload?

Answer (score -1):

I am using Jenkins to use CI/CD and i realised that it doesnt build for each push event by github

because it says "Specify the branches if you'd like to track a specific branch in a repository. If left blank, all branches will be examined for changes and built" according to Jenkins in the image below

[image]

If you are trying to parse in your own endpoint without using tools like Jenkins etc, you should parse the incoming response by branches