# How to trigger a Jenkins Pipeline on commit to a branch?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working on triggering a Jenkins Pipeline job when a commit is added to a particular branch on GitHub.

I do not see an appropriate Build Triggers on the Jenkins job options, like I would for a Jenkins Freestyle job.

How do I set a Jenkins Pipeline job to be triggered when a branch is updated with a new commit?

So far, I haven't found explicit answers to this scenario, [Only trigger Jenkins Pipeline job on commit to master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51102914/only-trigger-jenkins-pipeline-job-on-commit-to-master), only answered regarding Multi-branch jobs.

Any help on this question would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you figure out the solution yet? If so, can you please add as solution.

Answer (score 4):

To trigger a Jenkins pipeline with a new commit to Git branch you need to add the web hook on Git repository settings and select **Pushes** trigger event.

Or if you want Jenkins pipeline to perform some specific step on a specific branch .. you can try adding a condition in your Jenkinsfile like below..

```
def branchName = "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
if(branchName == 'dev'){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Is there anything settings required on the Jenkins Pipeline job that receives the Push trigger?

Comment: On the Jenkins server add the github server as repository. and you can also add the name of the Jenkinsfile you want to use in pipeline build configuration.

Comment: Within the Jenkins Pipeline Job, I have added the URL to the "GitHub project" box, and checked the Build Triggers option for "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling"

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a trigger in the repository in case of push for your branch. Additionally, you can poll the scm and define a cron for that.

Do not worry if you have several consecutive pushes in your branch. Jenkins is able to collapse multiple triggers in case of several executions in the queue.